# Deploy multiple-application to hololens 2

Tags: hololens

When I deploy the new application to hololens, the installed application is disappeared. So I can only deploy one application to the device. I use MRTKv2.4 and Unity2019.3 to make an application, and the names of unity project, scenes of unity, .sln file to build are different.

I think I am missing some basics to deploy an application, however, I'm still not what the exact problem is. Do you have any idea to check what the problem is, or even solve it to apply multiple applications to hololens?

p.s. I'm quite new for hololens, but also UWP app.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. Now I found the solution. Thanks to 'Hernando' I could trace where to look for. But it was not the 'DisplayName' it is the 'Identity Name'. That was same for both of my project. Reason was, the default identity name in Unity (I am using 2019.14.f1) is 'Template3D'. I kept it as it is for both and it caused the problem. You can either set it in Unity by File > Build Settings > Player > Publishing Settings > Package name OR go to the
YourProjectName > YourBuildDir > build > bin > ARM64 > Debug

- then open the file 'AppxManifest' and edit the <Identity Name= "theNameYouGive" ....

I made it same as my Display Name to avoid any confusion/conflict.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is due to the same package name of your two apps.

The identification of different applications does not base on the Unity project name or the scene name, but the `Package name` property in the `Package.appxmainfest` file. So, we think it is worth trying for you to update the `DisplayName` and `Package name` property in the Package.appxmainfest file with another name.

More information please see:  [Identity (Windows 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-identity)